# Why this recursive method for counting all the odd digits of a number makes infinite recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, methods, infinite

I have this exercise that asks me to create a program to count the odd digits of a number, so if the number is 12345 it will count to 3, because of 1, 3 and 5. I started creating a recursive method, my very first one, with a ramified if-else. The point of using it was to see `if (inputNumber % 2 == '0')`. If yes, the last digit of the number would be a 0, 2, 4, 6 or 8, because only those digits give 0 if moduled by 2, so oddDigitsCounter wouldn't grow. Else, `if (inputNumber % 2 == '1')`, the last digit of the number would be 1, 3, 5, 7 or 9. `oddDigitCounter++;`, so. To check digit by digit I tried to divide the number by ten because it is a `int` variable, so it doesn't saves any digit after the floating point.
This is the method since now:

```
public static int oddDigitCounter (int number) {

    int oddCount, moduledNumber, dividedNumber, absoluteInput;

    oddCount = 0;
    absoluteInput = Math.abs(number);
    moduledNumber = absoluteInput % 2;
    dividedNumber = absoluteInput / 10;

    if (absoluteInput == '0') {
        oddCount = oddCount;  }
    else if (moduledNumber == '0') {
        oddCount = oddCount;
        oddDigitCounter(dividedNumber); }
    else // (number % 2 != 0) 
        oddCount++;
        oddDigitCounter(dividedNumber); }

    return oddCount;
```

Why it gives me an infinite recursion? What's wrong? Why? Any other way to solve this? Any idea for improving my program?

Comment: It is surprising that @JunedAhsan comment is upvoted twice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare odd counter outside of recursion and you should get results :

```
static int oddCounts;

public static int oddDigitCounter(int number) {
    int moduledNumber, dividedNumber, absoluteInput = 0;

    absoluteInput = Math.abs(number);
    moduledNumber = absoluteInput % 2;
    dividedNumber = absoluteInput / 10;

    if (absoluteInput == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (moduledNumber == 0) {
        return oddDigitCounter(dividedNumber);
    } else {
        oddCounts++;
        return 1 + oddDigitCounter(dividedNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: A few changes to this, but it worked. The code was right, but I didn't initialize properly most of the variables. Oh, and you forgot to initialize 'oddCounts'. :)

Comment: Its okay, if you don't initialize class level variables.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the result of the recursive call. You also compared a integer to the character '0', which is not the same as comparing to 0.

```
public static int oddDigitCounter (int number) 
{
    int moduledNumber, dividedNumber, absoluteInput;

    inputAssoluto = Math.abs(numero);
    moduledNumber = absoluteInput % 2;
    dividedNumber = absoluteInput / 10;

    if (absoluteInput == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (moduledNumber == 0) {
        return oddDigitCounter(dividedNumber); 
    }
    else {
        return 1 + oddDigitCounter(dividedNumber); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should compare to `0` and not to `'0'`. The latter will be interpreted as `48`, the ASCII character for the numeral zero.

Furthermore, `absoluteInput` is never assigned to and will always have its initial value `0`. Where does `inputAssoluto` come from?

Comment: My fault, translation error with 'inputAssoluto', that is 'absoluteInput'. What's the difference between comparing to the ASCII character or to the integer digit 0?

Comment: Well, `0` and `'0'` are two very different things in Java. The first one is a number, and the second one is a character used in strings.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to list your numbers and then check each one as a single int again, meaning you can check digit by digit and don't have to divide the number by ten.

a very short solution will then suffice: (if your passing the number as a string the LINQ one-liner can give you what you want).

```
static int OddDigitCounter(int numbers)
{
    var c = numbers.ToString();
    var oddcount = c.Count(no => int.Parse(no.ToString()) % 2 != 0); //<--one liner 
    return oddcount;
}
```

Comment: Converting back and forth between string and int is a rather wasteful operation - object allocation is required, internal loops are called.

Comment: a single parse per digit should be less wasteful than the current solution of math operations and comparison call-backs. there are better ways of using the `IEnumeable<int> ` so for simplicities sake ...